# In XSL for-each, how to conditionally sort particular items unnaturally last?

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt

How would one sort records by a given field's value, except when that value has a special meaning, then it needs to go last.  In particular, below, when RX_Number = 'ADJ', the records needs to be at the bottom of the sort order.  Finally, within each of the groups, the records need to be sorted by date.

```
<xsl:variable name="rec" select="RecordP" />
<xsl:for-each select="$rec">
    <xsl:sort select="NPI"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="RX_Number = 'ADJ'">
            <!-- these should go last in sort order-->
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <!-- sort these by RX_Number (when not 'ADJ') -->
            <xsl:sort select="RX_Number" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:sort select="serviceDate"/>
    <!-- map nodes -->
</xsl:for-each>
```

Obviously the xsl:choose cannot go where it is.  I don't know how to arrange or construct the middle sort properly.  Desired sorting -- notice how 'ADJ' is pushed to the bottom of the results:

```
NPI     RX_Number     ServiceDate
1111      23456        20150410
1111      62453        20150410
2222      77777        20150410
2222      77777        20150411
2222      77777        20150413
3333      49891        20150413
2222      ADJ          20150413
```

version:  XSLT 1.0

Comment: Maybe create two groupings of records, one where RX_Number != 'ADJ' and the other where it is.  Then a for-each loop for each node set.  The trouble with that is I want to keep them together because I have to do totals later.

Comment: Having an actual XML input example to test with would have been nice.

Comment: @michael.hor257k yeh good idea.  i'll cleanse some.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
<xsl:for-each select="RecordP">
    <xsl:sort select="number(RX_Number='ADJ')" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
    <xsl:sort select="NPI"/>
    <xsl:sort select="ServiceDate" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
    <!-- do something with the sorted records -->
</xsl:for-each>
```

---

**Note**:

```
<xsl:sort select="RX_Number='ADJ'" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
```

would have served just as well, since "true" comes after "false" in alphabetical order.